# TailwindCSS responsive break points not working in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I've recently installed Tailwind for my Vue project. It took some time to get it work but finally, it worked, even with code completion in VS Code.

The problem I am facing right now is that I cannot use the breakpoints anywhere in my project.

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="card w-full sm:w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 xl:w-1/3">
        // Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Watch a gif of it.](https://i.imgur.com/MzXNVAQ.mp4)**

What I want to achieve is to have the div be 1/3 when on desktop, full width on mobile. What I am getting is full width everywhere. I can't seem to find anything else like this on the internet either.

I'd like to mention that I am using VueJS, if that's of any help. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually found the solution after a break and finding a Vue project that uses Tailwind. I needed to install [`postcss-preset-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-preset-env) and add it to `postcss.config.js`.

`npm install postcss-preset-env --save-dev`

**postcss.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-preset-env')({ stage: 0 }),
    require('tailwindcss')('tailwind.js'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

Comment: I had an issue with breakpoints not working for `container` css class only in version `1.4.6`. Just updating to newer version of tailwindcss helped.